# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, connection-string

This question may has been already put, but I do this for the first time and I don't know where I'm wrong.
I want to connect my asp.net web page to SQL Server 2012. My connection string is:

```
static private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U8B6J4S\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DBSera; User ID=DESKTOP-U8B6J4S\PROGRAMARE; Password=");
```

When I connect SQL:

[image]

[image]

The error I'm getting is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-U8B6J4S\PROGRAMARE'.

So what I did wrong and should I do to establish the connection? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Windows Authentication for SQL Server, don't specify User ID and Password in your connection string. Take those two parameters out completely.
By adding those parameters in, SQL Server thinks you want to use SQL authentication instead.

Use this connection string:

```
"Data Source=DESKTOP-U8B6J4S\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DBSera; Integrated Security=True;"
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''. `

Comment: What is your connection string now?

Comment: `static private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U8B6J4S\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DBSera;");
`

Comment: Head over to connectionstrings.com and read up on the parameters and examples. You do not activate the use of windows integrated authentication with this string.

Comment: @magn try adding Integrated Security=True; as in my answer